# enable breakpoint while debugging user input (gdb/linux)

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, x11

Recently I've been running into a problem where I want to enable a break-point in the middle of being in an interactive application (keyboard and mouse - dragging modal UI elements).

I want to be able to enable a break point once the application is already running and in the state I want.

The ability to ignore the breakpoint N times, can work - but dealing with mouse motion its a hassle to get right (not very predictable).

Ideally I could have a 3rd device (I joystick button of foot pedal for example), and press it when I want to enable the breakpoint.

Another option could be to SSH into my system from a second system and enable the breakpoint this way.

Is anyone aware of some good ways to interactively enable enable breakpoints while the application runs?

Answer (score 1):

When debugging an interactive X11 application, running the debugger from a separate workstation was pretty much a requirement ... until introduction of `Xvfb`.

These (running debugger from a separate workstation or running the app in `Xvfb`) are pretty much your two plausible choices.